# How to estimate the baseline cumulative hazard function with ties?

Tags: survival, cox-model, biostatistics, proportional-hazards

I know that in the proportional hazard model, Breslow estimator is used for estimating baseline cumulative hazard. But what about when the data has some(or many) ties?